# Extract data using regex or JSON

Tags: c#, json, regex

I have the following data in json format.

```
{
  "predictions": [
    {
      "prediction": "76A Fonthill Road, Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB11 6UL",
      "refs": "52833271",
      "complete": false
    },
    {
      "prediction": "76B Fonthill Road, Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB11 6UL",
      "refs": "52833272",
      "complete": false
    }
  ],
  "status": "Ok"
}
```

I have tried using Json.net but I can't get the data I need I want the address

```
76A Fonthill Road, Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB11 6UL
```

I have also tried using

```
regex Regex Exp = new Regex("\"prediction\":\"(.*),\"refs\"");
```

but it matches

> 76A Fonthill Road, Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB11 6UL","refs":"52833271","complete":false},{"prediction":"76B Fonthill Road, Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB11 6UL","refs"

It tried it in PHP with `json_decode()` and using Regex I can extract all the data properly.

> 76A Fonthill Road, Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB11 6UL \n
>   76B Fonthill Road, Aberdeen, Aberdeenshire, AB11 6UL \n*

I need a solution for c#.

Comment: It should be relatively simple to pull that data in C# out with JSON.NET.  Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I made a mistake in my code, but I am quite new to C#, I spent hours and figured out i spelt Prediction as Prediciton.

Answer (score 3):

Create set of classes that match your JSON.

```
 public class Predictions
{
    public string Prediction { get; set; }
    public string Refs { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}

public class PredictionsList
{
    public List<Predictions> Predictions { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then use JsonConvert to Deserialize

```
  var dataDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PredictionsList>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks Seminda, My code was very similar to yours, many thanks for the help.